# Spring MVC - Submit an Object from JSP

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a JSP that presents a list of customers (ArrayList searchResults).  I want to be able to pick one of those, and submit it to a Spring MVC controller.  However, it appears that I cannot pass the selected object, only a property of it, such as customerId.  I really need to pass the entire object.

Is there a standard way to do this in Spring 3.x?

```
<c:forEach items="${searchResults}" var="searchResult">
    <tr>
        <td><c:out value="${searchResult.customerId}" /></td>
        <td><c:out value="${searchResult.firstName}" /></td>
        <td><c:out value="${searchResult.lastName}" /></td>
        <td>
            <form method="POST" ACTION="./customercare">
                <input type="SUBMIT" value="Select This Customer"/>
                <input type="hidden" name ="searchResult" value="${searchResult}"/>
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Spring's `form` taglib](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/view.html#view-jsp-formtaglib) instead of plain `<form>` to post back to a Spring MVC Controller and then it will Bind the values back to the model you specify.

```
<form:form method="post" action="addContact.html">

<table>
<tr>
    <td><form:label path="firstname">First Name</form:label></td>
    <td><form:input path="firstname" /></td> 
</tr>
```

...

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addContact", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addContact(@ModelAttribute("contact")
                        Contact contact, BindingResult result) {
```

See this Post: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-3-mvc-handling-forms/

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider giving **id** to each  and nested tags to differentiate between row that you want to POST

```
<c:forEach items="${searchResults}" var="searchResult">
    <tr> 
....
            <form:form id="${searchResults.key}-form" method="POST" ACTION="./customercare">
                <form:input id="${searchResults.key}-btn" type="SUBMIT" value="Select This Customer"/>
                <form:input id="${searchResults.key}-hidden" type="hidden" name ="${searchResults.key}" value="searchResult['${searchResults.key}']"/>
            </form:form>

    </tr>
```

On the backend side you will have to write the controller as suggested by @PatBurke

Comment: This appears to be suggesting exactly what the question explicitly wanted to avoid (for whatever reason). Am I missing something?

Comment: As I understand: `SearchResults` is an ArrayList of `SearchResult` "Objects" . Each such object has 3 properties : `customer Id`, `first Name`, `Last Name`. If there are 2 such results returned lets say they would probably be stored as `SearchResults[0]` and `SearchResults[1]` where `0` and `1` are keys, which is passing the entire "Object" as per my question

Answer (score 0):

You could have 1 form per customer with a lot of hidden inputs in.  When that customer is selected you can POST that form.  Spring can then bind all the hidden inputs to your customer object.

(Generally, I would just send the id only and load the customer info, as an entity, from a Database.  However, I assume you must have a good reason for not wanting to do this)