# Two models in the form Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Suppose, I have a user model:

```
@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer id;

@Column(name="username")
private String username;

@Column(name="password")
private String password;

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="user_profile_id")
private UserProfile profile;
```

UserProfile model:

```
@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer id;

@Column(name="email")
private String email;

@Column(name="firstname")
private String firstname;

@Column(name="lastname")
private String lastname;
```

I can add this model in the controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/user/{id}"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showUser(ModelMap model, @PathVariable int id) {
    User user = userService.findById(id);
    model.addAttribute("user", user);

    return "UserView";
}
```

Then It's possible to access the model in the .jsp page like that:

```
<form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="user">
    <form:input type="text" path="username"/>
    <form:input type="password" path="password"/>
</form>
```

**But the question is** - how can I edit UserProfile model which is located in the User model at the same time while I'm editing User model which is passed from controller to .jsp page?

The question is not duplicate because I wanted to know if "path" can handle hierarchal attributes but not how just to pass one object to view.

Comment: Please be clearer. What do you want to edit? At what time? And what do you mean with "edit"?

Comment: Right. Are you wanting the HTML form to be able to also submit field values for like `user.profile.emailAddress`?

Comment: @dbreaux yes, exactly

Comment: @ImpulseTheFox I'm clicking add user, html form is opened with username and password inputs. But as you can see, I've got UserProfile object in the User model. It also has several fields like: email, name, surname. And I want to edit those fields at the same time while I'm editing username and password fields. So it actually looks like there are 5 inputs in the html form, two of which reference to the User model, the other 3 reference to the UserProfile model which is itself contained in the UserProfile model.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring MVC - Submit an Object from JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14530529/spring-mvc-submit-an-object-from-jsp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use like this

```
<form:input type="text" path="profile.email"/>
```

And I do not recomend you to pass your entity to front, instead use DTOs for decoupling

Comment: Yes, that ^. the `path` attribute can use hierarchical bean attributes.